# Mongodb $filter in aggregation for the multiple value date check

Tags: mongodb, filter, aggregation

I have a dataset like this:

```
"h_g" : [ 
        {
            "ip" : "111.111.22.22",
            "za" : 1,
            "zb" : 5,
            "cdate" : ISODate("2021-06-26T07:01:19.937Z"),
            "updatedAt" : [ 
                ISODate("2021-06-26T07:01:20.643Z"), 
                ISODate("2021-06-27T07:01:21.404Z"), 
                ISODate("2021-06-27T07:01:22.016Z"), 
                ISODate("2021-06-28T07:01:22.625Z"), 
                ISODate("2021-06-29T07:01:23.191Z")
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "ip" : "222.111.11.11",
            "za" : 1,
            "zb" : 3,
            "cdate" : ISODate("2021-06-28T07:01:29.026Z"),
            "updatedAt" : [ 
                ISODate("2021-06-28T07:01:29.609Z"), 
                ISODate("2021-06-289T07:01:30.174Z"), 
                ISODate("2021-06-29T07:01:30.696Z")
            ]
        }
]
```

Now I want to filter the data using $filter function through aggregation. I need to pick the data between two dates. I am able to do on the cdate column but not getting any idea about the updatedAt column.

This is my query about getting the data between the date range

```
db.getCollection('TableName').aggregate([
  { $project: { 
      h_g: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$h_g',
          as: 'content',
          cond: {
                $and: [
                {$gte: ['$$content.cdate', new Date('2021-06-27T18:30:00.000Z')]},
                {$lte: ['$$content.cdate', new Date('2021-06-29T18:30:00.000Z')]}
              ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I am looking for the suggestion for checking my date range exist on the updatedAt array or not.

Any help or interaction is really appreciated

Comment: Let me know please if what I suggest resolve your problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case if you want to check your date range inside the updateAt array, you should use $in instead of the $lte and $gte operators, here is my suggestion

```
db.getCollection('TableName').aggregate([
  { $project: { 
      h_g: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$h_g',
          as: 'content',
          cond: {
                $and: [
                {$in: [new Date('2021-06-27T18:30:00.000Z'), '$$content.updatedAt']},
                {$in: [ new Date('2021-06-29T18:30:00.000Z'), '$$content.updatedAt']}
              ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```